# installing two different versions of software on one machine

Tags: compilation, thrift

I'd like to install both thrift 0.8.0 and 0.9.0 on one machine. I have successfully downloaded both .tar.gz archives, `unpack`ed, `configure`d and ran `make`. When I ran `make install` fr 0.9.0, a binary executable `thrift` has been copied to `/usr/local/bin/thrift`. If I wanted to `make install` for 0.8.0, I guess there could be a huge mess, because the system would try to overwrite some files, unaware that the previous version is installed. How can I install compiled two versions of thrift on one machine e.g. to have it accesible via `thrift-0.8.0` and `thrift-0.9.0`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `configure` program accepts a large number of arguments; one of which is `--prefix=<dir>`.  The default is `--prefix=/usr/local`. In your case, compile each version with a different prefix.  For example:

```
$ cd .../thrift.0.8.0/...
$ configure --prefix=/usr/local/thrift/0.8.0
$ make install
```

and then

```
$ cd .../thrift.0.9.0/...
$ configure --prefix=/usr/local/thrift/0.9.0
$ make install
```

Then, you modify your PATH (MANPATH, etc) to use either of /usr/local/thrift/0.{8,9}.0/bin